# How to add bold style to a substring in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a list of strings like this:

```
[
    {
       text: "This is a sentence."
       boldSubstrings: [
           { offset: 5, length: 2 }
       ]
    }
]
```

I want to render a list of lines like this

```
 lines.map(elem => <p>{elem.text}</p>);
```

and I need to somehow apply bold style to the words indicated in boldSubstrings (In this example "This **is** a sentence."), any idea how?

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
const stringList = [
  {
     text: "This is a sentence.",
     boldSubstrings: [
         { offset: 5, length: 2 },
         { offset: 8, length: 1 }
     ]
  }
];

stringList.map(({text, boldSubstrings}) => {
  let prevStart = 0;
  const splittedStrings = [];
  for (let subStrings of boldSubstrings) {
    splittedStrings.push(text.substr(prevStart, subStrings.offset - prevStart));
    splittedStrings.push(<b>{text.substr(subStrings.offset, subStrings.length)}</b>);
    prevStart = subStrings.offset + subStrings.length;
  }
  splittedStrings.push(text.substr(prevStart));
  return <p>{splittedStrings}</p>;
});
```

Produces:

```
<p>This <b>is</b> <b>a</b> sentence.</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget the `key` when rendering arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This component should do it. Similar to answer above, but I've written it now! It assumes that the bold substrings are always sorted, and it doesn't do any arguments checking, so watch out!

```
function FormattedLine({ text, boldSubstrings }) {
  let position = 0;
  const fragments = [];

  boldSubstrings.forEach(({ offset, length }) => {
    if (position < offset) {
      const paragraph = text.substr(position, offset - position);
      fragments.push({ text: paragraph, isBold: false });
    }
    if (length) {
      fragments.push({ text: text.substr(offset, length), isBold: true });
      position = offset + length;
    }
  });

  if (position < text.length) {
    fragments.push({
      text: text.substr(position, text.length - position),
      isBold: false
    });
  }

  return (
    <p>
      {fragments.map(({ text: fragmentText, isBold }) =>
        isBold ? <b>{fragmentText}</b> : fragmentText
      )}
    </p>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-substring-styler`. It does exactly what you want without disrupting the project structure and how you store your texts.

```
npm install react-substring-styler or yarn add react-substring-styler
```

code:

```
const text = "This text is going to be [bold]."

<ParsedText patterns={
     [{type: "squareBrackets", style: {fontWeight: "bold"}}]}>
       {text}
 </ParsedText>
```

More info at https://github.com/pborgesjr/react-substring-styler
or at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-substring-styler